# LDA topic model: Error in !all.equal(x$v, as.integer(x$v)) : invalid argument type

Tags: r

I am trying to run an LDA topic model in R. I have created a document term matrix, which looks good and tried fitting an LDA model to it. However, I just keep getting the same error: Error in !all.equal(x$v, as.integer(x$v)) : invalid argument type

This is the code I used:

---

---

````
XR_data_counts <- map_df(1:2, ~ unnest_tokens(Merged_XR_new, words, title,
                                                         token = "ngrams", n = .x)) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = "words")%>%
  count(id, words, sort =TRUE)


XR_words_10 <- XR_data_counts %>% 
  group_by(words) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  filter(n >= 12) %>%
  select(words)

XR_data_dtm <- XR_data_counts %>%
  right_join(XR_words_10, by = "words")%>%
  bind_tf_idf(words,id, n)%>%
  cast_dtm(id, words, tf_idf)%>% 
  na.omit()

# here it stops working 
XR_lda <- topicmodels::LDA(XR_data_dtm, k = 2, control=list(seed=240))

XR_lda```
````